# Use a mysql returned variable in IOS app for otherJSON calls

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a app and I connect with `Json` to a `mysql` DB using `PHP` and return a value ( `UserID` ). I now would like to use that value returned for other `JSON` calls in my `WHERE` statements.

Do i store the value in a plist file?
How do i make that a global value for that specific user?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to save this value in your `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// write value
[defaults setInteger:value forKey:@"value"];
[defaults synchronize];

// read
// if value is not an int but an NSNumber, change it to [defaults objectForKey:@"value"]
value = [defaults intForKey:@"value"];
```

Comment: Perfect, i think this will do! Thanks

Comment: Yes, just testing it quick. then will do!

Answer (score 0):

Historically on iOS, the device UDID has been used as a user's ID in databases. That's recently been banned by Apple, so unless you're forcing users to register with a username and password, you should use the vendor ID as their user ID in the database. The vendor ID is determined using:

```
NSString* vendorID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

You should pass this value to the server and insert it into your user table as the user's ID.

Comment: MMM, interesting. Yes, the user logs in with his username and password from the website. But 'im not allowing them to register from the app. I was hoping once logged in and i return the id, i could use it for other queries in the app.

Comment: I get the ID once connected, but how do i make that a global value for the other JSON calls?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to make users register for accounts--most mobile apps avoid doing this, because lots of users will just stop when faced with a registration screen. Generally you shouldn't try to save the user ID on the client, because you can't trust the client ever. If you just blindly use the user ID, one user could easily get access to another's data. I recommend passing the username / password in every JSON call as part of HTTP basic authentication, and make sure your connections go over HTTPS so the username / password are not visible. You really need to use good security practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSUserDefault` to store any variable that is common throughout the application. You can add the object in it and you can remove that when application terminates or that particular User logs out from the application.

e.g.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"10" forKey:@"UserID"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

And to remove

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"UserID"];
```